# Python watch QNAP FTP directory for changes and send UDP messages

Tags: python, ftp, qnap

I need to write a program that watches a directory on ftp server and then sends a message with the path to the new file. So I did manage to use `watchdog` for a local folder with this as I need just the create event:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = "*"
    ignore_patterns = ""
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = False
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

    def on_created(event):
        byte_message = bytes(f"{event.src_path}", "utf-8")
        opened_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        opened_socket.sendto(byte_message, ('address', port))
        print(f"{event.src_path} created")
    
    my_event_handler.on_created = on_created

    path = r"local/path"
    go_recursively = True
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

    my_observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
```

But when I try replacing the `path` with the folder on that FTP I get `Access Denied` which is correct as I did't set the login and the password. After that I did this, based on an answer on Stack Overflow:

```
ftp = FTP()
ftp.set_pasv(True)
ftp.connect("address")
ftp.login('user', 'pass')

def changemon(dir='ftp/path/*'):
    ls_prev = set()

    while True:
        ls = set(ftp.nlst(dir))

        add = ls-ls_prev
        if add: 
            yield add 
        ls_prev = ls
        sleep(5)

for add in changemon():
    byte_message = bytes('\n'.join(r'address%' % i for i in add), 'utf-8')
    opened_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    opened_socket.sendto(byte_message, ('address', port))
```

The problem with this is that it gets every single file that appears in the `dir`.

So I need something that I can extract the subfolder names and file names from. Like this: `file1` and `file2` are newly created:

```
ftp/path/5000/file1
ftp/path/5001/file2

print('Folder is: ' + foldername)
Folder is: 5000
Folder is: 5001
print('New file is: ' + filename)
New file is: file1
New file is: file2
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The first time it runs it will always return every file, because your `ls_prev` will be empty. So if this code is inside a process that ends and restarts, you'll have to find a way to save the value of `ls_prev` and read it back before entering the loop. A simple pickle should work just fine for that. Keep in mind that this will not detect a file being changed (a new version of the same file name uploaded).

Comment: @T0ny1234 this causes a lot of noise, you are sure you only can run that code remotely ?

Comment: @user3732793 Yes, it's for monitoring an QNAP ftp directories. And this is the only way I figured how to do the task. If you have the time can you suggest a better way?

Comment: depends what qnap you have. looks like some have SNMP interfaces. Here a icinga plugin https://github.com/Mikesch-mp/qnap_health

Comment: @user3732793 Thanks I didn't know that existed. Can it be used for the result I want to achieve i.e watch directory and send udp/tcp message?

Comment: SNMP is used for network devices management. So yes you can write a script  loop over these calls and the device tells you what is going on..some learn curve is involved

Comment: Thanks again, I will look at the pysnmp and start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution after me not able to find anything that could help me from the store (and the task was to make it in python):

```
from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep
import os
import byte
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ftp = FTP()
ftp.set_pasv(True)
ftp.connect("some-ip-address")
ftp.login('user', 'password')

def changemon(dir='/dir/*'):
    ls_prev = set()

    while True:
        ls = set(ftp.nlst(dir))

        add = ls-ls_prev
        if add:
            yield add

        ls_prev = ls
        sleep(5)

#tcp
for add in changemon():
    result = [i for i in add]
    array = np.array(result, dtype='str')
    df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=None, index=None)
    for a in array:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host, port))
        name = a.split('/')
        separator = ''
        path = (r'ip\dir\\' + str(name[2]) + '\\' + str(name[3]))
        device = name[2]
        message = bytes(separator.join(f'{device} desired string for the IP notification  \n'), 'utf-8')
        s.send(message)
        sleep(5)
```

It's not the prettiest solution, but gets the job done. The slashes are in the oposite direction because the message needs to be read in Windows. The `path` variable is then inserted in a database.